# Find cells containing not null value between date range in Excel

Tags: excel, vlookup, countif

I have a table where Column A is a list of every day this year. In column E I have hours worked on each given day. Some of these cells are blank for days not worked. Because I've also entered work hours on some weekends, it's important I isolate the weekdays in this query

I need to know the number of WEEKDAYS from column A between the start date (A2) and TODAY where there IS A VALUE in column E.

In other words the number of NETWORKDAYS between A2 and TODAY where the value in column E is NOT NULL.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you use Josh's suggestion but use a slight variation, e.g. in `F2` copied down you can use this formula

`=WEEKDAY(A2,2)`

Using that version Saturdays = 6 and Sundays = 7 so to count weekdays so far this year with hours in column E you can then use `COUNTIFS` like this:

`=COUNTIFS(A:A,"<="&TODAY(),E:E,"<>",F:F,"<6")`

......or it's possible to do the same without a helper column (column F) if you use `SUMPRODUCT`, e.g.

`=SUMPRODUCT((A2:A400<=TODAY())*(WEEKDAY(A2:A400,2)<6)*(E2:E400<>""))`

Comment: THANK YOU Barry! Your 2nd option was exactly what I was after - hadn't even considered SUMPRODUCT. Great work!

Answer (score 0):

The quickest way to do this is to add a column in which each cell is =WEEKDAY(A2), all the way down. This will give you the day of the week. Then just filter your data: assuming your weekend is Saturday and Sunday, filter out 1 and 7 in the 'weekday' column, then filter out blanks in Column E, and then just select Column A and the COUNT (number of cells) will be displayed in [the bottom right corner](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Al2a1.png).

Comment: Thanks Josh, and yes, going this route would give me a one-time count, but I need this to be an active function so as the days go by, the sheet adapts (which is why I'd like to use the date range from cell A2 through TODAY(). There has to be a way to do this with COUNTIFS, but all my trial and error has just yielded #ERRORs.